# range slider in angular 2 is not working

Tags: jquery, angular

when i change the value of the slider in angular 2 using j query ,it is not triggering the slide function and also the change function..

```
    jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find("#slider").slider({

        range: true,

        orientation: "horizontal",

        min: 0,

        max: 100,

        step: 1, 

        value: [80, 100],

        slide: (event, ui) => {
            alert("hai");

        },
        change: (event, ui) => {
            alert("hai");

        },
    });


}
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you the value of the slider? Because you use `range: true`, you need to provide an array of values and set them using the `values` attribute:

```
jQuery(...).slider({
  (...)
  values: [30, 80],
  (...)
});
```

To set the values after having created the slider use the following:

```
this.sliderElt.slider('values', values);
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/jIRZLvfZVe7RgIceEiNS?p=preview

Comment: how to pass both the values from the on change to sliderValue??

Comment: The `ngModel` can reference an array ;-)